# Installing and running spyder3 in Debian Stretch

Tags: python3, spyder

The stable version (3.1.3) in the Debian Stretch repository is kind of old (https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=spyder3).

So, I installed the 3.2.6 version via `pip3 install spyder --user`.

How can I run it? Tried: `spyder`, `spyder3`, `python3-spyder` `python3 spyder`. It was installed correctly and can be imported into an interactive shell.

Comment: [Don't suffer from Shiny New Stuff Syndrome](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_suffer_from_Shiny_New_Stuff_Syndrome).    If you really need newer stuff (hint: you probably don't actually **need** it), then add `APT::Default-Release "stable";` to an apt.conf file, then add the `unstable` repository to your sources.list and run `apt-get -t unstable install shinynewstuff`.   The `-t unstable` overrides the default `stable` distribution.

Comment: @cas: I'm normally quite happy with the stable version provided by apt. However, in this case it's different. There's a bug popping up that was corrected on the 3.1.4 version.

Comment: the packaged version in testing & unstable is 3.2.4+dfsg1-1, with packages for both python 3.6 (package name "sypder3") and python 2.7 ("spyder").

Answer (score 1):

For running the IDE after installing it through `pip`:

Find where it's installed with `pip3 show spyder`. It will be something like: `.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages`.

Go to the subdirectory `spyder/app/`, there you'll find `start.py`. Run it with `python3 start.py`.